# find value of $p+q+r$ in probability problem

Tags: probability

A plaindrome is choosen randomly between $1000$ and $10000$

if the probability that it is divisible by $7$ is $p/10;$

the probability that it is divisible by $11$ is $q/10;$

the probability that it is divisible by  $13$ is $r/10$

then find value of $p+q+r$ is

what i try

total number of $4$ digit palindrome is $10\times 9=90$

let palindrome is $\Rightarrow abba$

$\underline{\text{Divisible by 11}}$

$abba=1000a+100b+10b+a=1001a+110b$

how do i solve it help me please

Comment: Remember, to test for divisibility by $11$ you take the alternating sum of the digits.

Comment: Note: your palindrome is $abba$, but $a$ cannot be $0$, while $b$ can be zero. That may be worth remembering as you do further computations. (I'm not certain, not having done them myself.)

Answer (score 2):

Expressing the palindrome as $1000a+110b$ is a good start to finding the solution.

Some useful points:

- $ \left( x \bmod n = 0 \right) \land \left( y \bmod n = 0 \right) \to (x + y) \bmod n = 0 $
- $ \left( x \bmod n = 0 \right) \lor \left( y \bmod n = 0 \right) \to (x \times y) \bmod n = 0 $
- $ 1001 = 7 \times 11 \times 13 $
- $ 110 = 2 \times 5 \times 11 $

Look at the divisibility of $1001a$ and $110b$, and see if you can find the solution from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What is the number $1001a + 110b$, taken $\bmod 11$?